# What does 有多 mean?

Tags: meaning

Today, while scrolling through my Instagram feed, I found this saying :

> 你不需要有多完美，也可以做得很好。

I wonder what 有多 means. I tried to look for its meaning on the dictionary but it's not listed as a single word.

Could someone please explain its meaning and function here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

有多  functions similar to "being how" in English

Example:

完美= perfect

多完美 = how perfect

有多完美 = being how perfect

强大 = strong

多强大 = how strong

有多强大 = being how strong

Example sentence:

不管他技巧[**有多**]完美,實力[**有多**]强大, 他也不是我對手

No matter [**how**] perfect his skill [**is**], [**how**] strong his power [**is**], he is still no match for me.

Answer (score 2):

你不需要有多完美，也可以做得很好。
You don't need to be absolutely perfect, you can also do it.
You don't need to be that perfect, you can also do it.

I understand 不需要有多完美 as: don't need to have great perfection, don't need that much perfection

你有多爱我？
How much do you love me?
从这里去那里有多远?。
How far is it from here to there?

Answer (score 2):

有多 is not a phrase, so you won't find it in a dictionary. The right split is 你不需要有 | 多完美。means you don't have to be perfect to do something.